# How to resize images in css in email signature?

Tags: html, css, email

I have a problem with my email signature. I can see it very well, but when the recipient sends a reply the images are very large and the css is no longer taken into account (I can see it in his return email). I do not understand why ?

Here is the code:

```html
<img style = "width: 180px; height: 96px" width = "180px"; height = "96px" src = "liendelimage">
```

I tried two versions to put the size but in both cases it does not work!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem, I believe its an Issu of the Email programs and the only way which helped me, was to reduce the image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your second width and height is wrong, e.g a spurious ; (semi-colon).

However, that's probably not the main problem.

Some email clients ignore styling, though inline styles as you have are more likely to succeed than separate CSS definitions in `<head>` for example.

Reducing the image size as suggested by @hamid will help in some cases.

However, some clients will ignore HTML altogether and even more will have images switched off by default so always show your name in plain text too.